# kernel module of Windows that can be found NDIS in memory Windows

Tags: visual-c++, ndis

I want to write a kernel module of Windows 7 that can be found in the Windows memory and to access the module NDIS. How to implement? What to read on the subject? You can sample code in C + +

Answer (score 0):

WinDDk provides some sample drivers. You may take help of those sample drivers. There is one website [ndis.com](http://ndis.com/). Here you can get more information related to ndis internals. If you are new in ndis, you can start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570709(v=vs.85).aspx) and try to understand passthru driver which is an ndis intermediate driver and given inside WinDDk sample drivers.